# Why is my for loop for plotting printing and generating figures out of order?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib, spyder

My for loop, presented here, is supposed to generate a plot for each year. It is supposed to print the year, then show a figure. But what happens is, all of the years get printed first, then all of the figures get printed.

On top of that. There is an empty figure that gets printed at the very end.

I am using Spyder for the record.

Pics attached to show the outputs.

Can you please help me understand what is happening here so that I can control my outputs in the future?

Thank you so much.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.figure(0)

for i in range(5):
    k=2014+i
    crimesyear=crimes.loc[crimes['Year'].isin([k])]
    crimesyear.groupby('Month')['INCIDENT_ID'].c**strong text**ount().plot(marker='o')
    plt.figure(i+1)
    plt.xticks(numpy.arange(12),months)
    plt.ylabel('Number of Crimes')
    plt.show
    print(k)
```

[First part of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRfwW.jpg)

[Last part of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72eOo.jpg)

Comment: Are you just searching for a way to give the plots a title that contain the year in it or do you really need to have it printed on stdout?

Comment: I was just printing it out for my own reference. Honestly, at this point I would want to title each one with a year, but still, what is happening is strange and I would like to know WHY it is occurring to increase my understanding of python. So, yes to both really

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matplotlib has a way of generating plots without using the stateful interface. This should help you generate plots in a loop.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(nrows=2, ncols=1, figsize=(5, 10))

for i, a in enumerate(ax):
    a.plot(np.arange(10))
    a.set_title(f'test {i}')
```

Check out the Object-Oriented API of matplotlib [here](https://matplotlib.org/tutorials/introductory/lifecycle.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simplified version of your graphs without all the data.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(5):
    k=2014+i
    plt.figure(i)
    plt.title(str(k))
    plt.ylabel('Number of Crimes')
plt.show()
```

Your extra blank graph came from the `plt.figure(0)` at the start. You only need to do `plt.show()` once at the end. You can set the titles using `plt.title(<string goes here>)`. In general, displaying something is an asynchronous call to another program, so it is often difficult to predict the order that you'll see things - I'm not familiar with spyder for the specifics here.